# Dragule + Bootstrap: mirror image missing while dragging

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, dragula

I set up dragula with Bootstrap 3, dragging images enclosed in a div, in a div container. Drag and drop between containers works fine, repositioning too, but the mirror image (the shadow) does not appear, not the preview at the target. What do I look for. Is there an option to enable this?

Comment: I also noticed this. No answer yet. Did you discover why???

Comment: no I did not, I'm sorry, and then moved on to some other tool

Comment: I found that this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44820132/2141465), on a somewhat related question, helped me solve a problem I was having similar to yours.